# Как узнать цвет фона документа с помощью OpenXml?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

Можна пройтись по элементам документа

```
List<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement> elements = docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ToList();
```

OR

```
List<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement> elements = docx.MainDocumentPart.Document.ToList();
```

Но тут нету цвета фона самого документа

```
foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlElement element in elements)
{
    List<RunProperties> runProps = element.Descendants<RunProperties>().ToList();
    foreach (RunProperties rp in runProps)
    {
        rp.Color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это вы его с xml файла вытягиваете? можно xml тоже показать? Обязательно использование DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Comment: Пример xml -> http://xopusfiddle.net/2ffnU/  Нет, использование DocumentFormat.OpenXml необязательно, но как еще можна работать с OpenXml?

Comment: [такой](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/16.2.php) способ подходит Вам?

Comment: мне непонятно как узнать цвет фона документа. Можна попробовать использовать System.Xml, но как это поможет узнать цвет фона?

Comment: Подозреваю, что он там в стилях.

Comment: У меня цвет документа лежит в "document.xml" в `<w:background w:color="здесь"/>`, у вас такого я не вижу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду цвет, который устанавливается в <kbd>Разметка страницы</kbd><kbd>Фон страницы</kbd><kbd>Цвет страницы</kbd>, то он лежит в `file.docx/word/document.xml` в атрибуте `color` тега `background`, в корневом теге `document` и у меня получилось достать его с помощью следующего кода:

```
using (var file = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, isEditable: false))
{
    foreach (var db in file.MainDocumentPart.Document.ChildElements.OfType<DocumentBackground>())
        Console.WriteLine(db.Color);
}
```

Но имейте ввиду, что его там может и не быть (в вашем документе я его не вижу).

Comment: в том то и проблема, что я тоже не вижу цвета и не понимаю что надо сделать чтобы его увидеть и вытащить

Comment: Скиньте документ, посмотрим

Comment: кажется разобрался, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Расскажете? ....